# list not adding all values in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json

i tried below code for create json code ,code working fine.

i was load value from db,but last value only i got a output .remaining value not added..

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var objectToSerialize = new RootObject();
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString());
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from IFlicksMenu", connection);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
da.Fill(dt);

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    { 
        objectToSerialize.contacts = new List<Cont> 
        {
            new Cont
            { 
                sno = dr["Cinema"].ToString(), 
                name = dr["Gallery"].ToString(), 
                address =  dr["star"].ToString(), 
                gender =  dr["video"].ToString(), 
                em = dr["em"].ToString(),
                phone=new Phone { mobile=dr["phonone"].ToString() } 
            },
        };          
    }

    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(new { item = objectToSerialize.contacts }));
}
```

output is

```
{
    "item":[
         {
        "phone":{
            "mobile":"99528748474"
                },
        "sno":"ACTRESS",
        "name":"ACTRESS",
        "em":"scd",
        "address":"ACTRESS",
        "gender":"TRAILER"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You are creating a new `List` in your foreach... Try creating it OUTSIDE your foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You recreate `contacts` for each item when you want create in on the beginning of the loop and keep adding to the list:

```
var items = new List<Cont>();
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{ 
    items.Add(new Cont{ 
        sno = dr["Cinema"].ToString(), 
        name = dr["Gallery"].ToString(), 
        address =  dr["star"].ToString(), 
        gender =  dr["video"].ToString(), 
        em = dr["em"].ToString(),
        phone = new Phone{ mobile=dr["phonone"].ToString() }
    });
}
objectToSerialize.contacts = items;
```

also you need to remove internal loop

```
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
```

as it will effectively multiply number of rows by number of columns

Answer (score 3):

You are instantiating list inside `foreach` for every iteration so it takes the final iteration.you can define List object outside `foreach` and values inside `foreach`

```
List<Cont> ContCollection =  new List<Cont>();
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    { 
        ContCollection.Add(new Cont(){
                            sno = dr["Cinema"].ToString(), 
                            name = dr["Gallery"].ToString(), 
                            address =  dr["star"].ToString(), 
                            gender =  dr["video"].ToString(), 
                            em = dr["em"].ToString(),
                            phone=new Phone { mobile=dr["phonone"].ToString() }
                           });


    }
    objectToSerialize.contacts = ContCollection;
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(new { item = objectToSerialize.contacts }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
objectToSerialize.contacts.Add( new List<Cont> 
{
    new Cont{ sno = dr["Cinema"].ToString(), name = dr["Gallery"].ToString(), address =  dr["star"].ToString(), gender =  dr["video"].ToString(), em = dr["em"].ToString(),phone=new Phone{mobile=dr["phonone"].ToString()} },
});
```

instead of

```
objectToSerialize.contacts = new List<Cont> 
{
    new Cont{ sno = dr["Cinema"].ToString(), name = dr["Gallery"].ToString(), address =  dr["star"].ToString(), gender =  dr["video"].ToString(), em = dr["em"].ToString(),phone=new Phone{mobile=dr["phonone"].ToString()} },
};
```